# YouTube video subscription username and email id using PHP and JSON

Tags: php, json, youtube, youtube-api, file-get-contents

I have a code like this.

```
    <?php 
    $data = file_get_contents('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/userid?alt=json');
    $data = json_decode($data, true);
    $stats_data = $data['entry']['yt$statistics'];

    echo 'subscriberCount = '.$stats_data['subscriberCount'].'<br />';
    echo 'viewCount = '.$stats_data['viewCount'].'<br />';
    ?>
```

I would like to get the details of the subscribers to my YouTube video.

For ex:
If i have a video haan.avi and upload it to YouTube and if the subscriber count is 5. I need to take the details of my subscriber to my video such as subscriber email id and username.

For ex: if Haan (YouTube user) is having 5 subscribers who are following a video and subscribed to that video, I need the list of those 5 members like their username, email id etc..

Comment: This is too broad, voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

Once the userid is replaced your code is working fine.
However by default api version 1 is used. Add the 'v' parameter in order to use version 2.
The api documentation will show you what information is available.
(The email is NOT listed and therefor NOT available).

Change of your example:

```
$realUserName = 'megannicolesite'; // Replace by a real YouTube username
$data = file_get_contents('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/' . $realUserName . '?v=2&alt=json');
$data = json_decode($data, true);
$stats_data = $data['entry']['yt$statistics'];

echo 'subscriberCount = '.$stats_data['subscriberCount'].'<br />';
echo 'viewCount = '.$stats_data['viewCount'].'<br />';
echo 'userId = '. $data['entry']['yt$userId']['$t'].'<br />';
echo 'username = '. $data['entry']['yt$username']['$t'].'<br />';
echo 'displayname = '. $data['entry']['yt$username']['display'].'<br />';
```

Comment: Als - I dont want the username or the display name.
For ex: if haan is having 5 subscribers who are following a video, i need the list of those 5 members like their username, email id etc..

Comment: You need to get a list of the subscribers first, then you can list information for those channels. You can get a list of subscribers for a channel using an authenticated request and using api version 3.

Comment: See: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#try-it ; However there are some issues, like missing or duplicate names; See:  https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=3742&q=label%3AAPI-YouTube&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary ; An email is considered private information, therefor not available. This is about subscribers of a channel. But subscribers following a video ? Never heard it before.